# Nullpointer on Mockito when

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, mockito

I use following test to test my utitiliesclass, I use mockito for the sql connection.

```
    @Mock
    public Connection connectionMock;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }    
@Test
    public void testResource(){
        String sql = Utilities.resourceToString("testSql.sql");
        try {
            Mockito.when(connectionMock.createStatement().executeQuery(sql)).thenAnswer(new Answer<String>() {
                @Override
                public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
                    return "X";
                }
            });
```

I get a nullpointer on the line Mockito.when, what is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need another mock...

```
connectionMock.createStatement()
```

...will return null unless you set up an expectation for it.

For example, add...

```
@Mock
private Statement statement;

...

when(connectionMock.createStatement()).thenReturn(statement);
when(statement.executeQuery(sql)).thenAnswer(...);
```

### Update

To answer the comment below, you should be returning a result set, not a string. For example...

```
@Mock
private ResultSet resultSet;

...

when(statement.executeQuery(sql)).thenReturn(resultSet);
when(resultSet.getString(1)).thenReturn("X");

... call the class under the test...

// Add verification that "next" was called before "getString"...
// (not 100% necessary, but makes it a more thorough test)
InOrder order = inOrder(resultSet);
order.verify(resultSet).next();
order.verify(resultSet).getString(1);
```

Update #2

Removed stuff that was wrong

Comment: You could also just do *thenReturn("X")* instead of *thenAnswer(...)*

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.sql.ResultSet, is now the error on the assertion part

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS`;

In your code it would look something like that:

```
    public Connection connectionMock;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        connectionMock = Mockito.mock(Connection.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
    }
    
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually, you can have a better usage about Mockito:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
 public class ExampleTest {
     @Mock
     public Connection connectionMock;     
 }
```

Comment: this is 100% near the question.