# how to mock a fluent api with static method calls in it?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mocking, mockito, powermock

I have scenario like i need to test a method which uses a fluent api with static method calls in it. I am able to mock upto the static call but i dont know how to mock the whole fluent method calls and return the corresponding output.

Scenario:

Test class:

```
 public class CustomerManagementService {
   /**
    * This method is used to verify the fluent api
    * @return
    */
     public String fluentApiVerificationWithStatic(){

        Customer customer=PaltformRuntime.getInstance().getElementRegistry().getElement();

        return customer.getName();
    }
}
```

PaltformRuntime class:

```
 public class PaltformRuntime {

    public static PaltformRuntime paltformRuntime = null;

    public static PaltformRuntime getInstance(){

        if(null == paltformRuntime) {
            paltformRuntime = new PaltformRuntime();
        }
        return paltformRuntime;
    }

     public PaltformRuntime getElementRegistry(){

         return paltformRuntime;
    }

    public Customer getElement(){       

        Customer c=new Customer();
         return c;
     }
 }
```

Test case:

```
 @Test
 public void fluentVerificationwithStatic() throws Exception {  

    PaltformRuntime instance = PaltformRuntime.getInstance();       
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(PaltformRuntime.class);

    PowerMockito.when(PaltformRuntime.getInstance()).thenReturn(instance);


    CustomerManagementService customerManagementService=new CustomerManagementService();

    String result = customerManagementService.fluentApiVerificationWithStatic();

    //assertEquals(customer.getName(), result);

}
```

As you can see the code , I am able to mock  **PaltformRuntime.getInstance()**  but if i try to mock **PaltformRuntime.getInstance().getElementRegistry().getElement()** and returns customer object i am getting an null pointer exception in getElementRegistry() call.
    I am able to mock fluent api without any static methods in it.But in this sceanrio i got stuck.
   I dont know what am missing ? please suggest how to mock the fluent api with static methods in it.

Comment: Why are you not using a mock in place of `PaltformRuntime.getInstance()` so that 'instance' is a mock?

Comment: Yes , instance is a mock I tried to check whether I am able to mock up to PaltformRuntime.getInstance(). I am able to do that. If I try to mock like When ( PaltformRuntime.getInstance().getElementRegistry().getElement()).then return(customer); I am getting null pointer exception

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29670806/nullpointer-on-mockito-when/29670988#29670988

Answer (score 1):

Use deep stubbing for `PaltformRuntime` instance

```
@Test
public void fluentVerificationwithStatic() throws Exception {  

    Customer customer = new Customer();

    PaltformRuntime instance = Mockito.mock(PaltformRuntime.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
    when(instance.getElementRegistry().getElement()).thenReturn(customer);

    PowerMockito.mockStatic(PaltformRuntime.class);
    PowerMockito.when(PaltformRuntime.getInstance()).thenReturn(instance);

    CustomerManagementService customerManagementService=new CustomerManagementService();
    String result = customerManagementService.fluentApiVerificationWithStatic();

    assertEquals(customer.getName(), result);
}
```